# Can I upload application in Google play console as same name as I uploaded before?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have a Play console account and a developer created an app and I uploaded in it. Now the developer asking huge amount for update the app. So I created another app with the same app name and different package name. Can I upload the app in play console? Can anyone give a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

**YES**.

The app generic name can be the same as another app available in the store. The only important thing is that the **application id** (package name). is unique, the one defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Check [Best practices for private apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/9496237?hl=en):

> Your app's package name must be globally unique in Google Play (not just unique within your enterprise or Google Play Developer account). If your package name is the same as a package name already in Google Play, then recompile your app with a different package name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upload the application on the [Google Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play) store by changing its package name.

For uploading an app on the store, use [this link](https://appinventiv.com/blog/how-to-submit-app-to-google-play-store/).